# Read line by line from STDIN and write it in output file

Tags: c

For one part of my homework I need to take input line by line from user and print it in output file, but I always get empty file.

I made it to work in different scenario, when it's reads from file and writes result in file. But in this case I just can't figure it out what I am doing wrong.

```
while(-1 != (nchr = getline(&buffer, &buffer_size, stdin)))
    {
        if(buffer == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

            //last line in file without \n ??
        buffer[--nchr] = '\0';

        char tmp[nchr];
        strcpy(tmp, buffer);


        if(optionI){
            convertToLow(buffer);
        }
        if(optionS){
            deblank(buffer);
        }
        if(optionO){

            //  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //  won't print in file
            //  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


            if (is_ok(buffer)) {

                fprintf(outfile,"%s is ok\n", tmp);
            } else {
                fprintf(outfile,"%s is not ok\n", tmp);
            }




        } else{

            if (is_ok(buffer)) {
                printf("%s is ok\n", tmp);
            } else {
                printf("%s is not ok\n", tmp);
            }
        }   
    }


    free(buffer); 


}     
fclose(outfile); 
fflush(stdout); 
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  The function: `fflush()` is for output streams and `stdin` is an input stream.  The C standard specifically states that that statement is undefined behavior.  Suggest using: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){}`

Comment: regarding: ` if(buffer == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }`  This is not needed and can be deleted.  If the memory allocation fails, the function returns -1, which the posted code is already checking

Comment: regarding: `buffer[--nchr] = '\0';`  this is not a reliable method of removing a trailing newline.   Suggest:  `buffer[ strspn( buffer, "\n" ) } = '\0';`

Comment: I cant use getchar() because program must accept lines of any length.

Comment: the call to `getchar()` is for the purpose of clearing out `stdin`, it is called in a loop, so will consume all characters that are still in `stdin`

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for strspn( buffer, "\n" )

Comment: regarding: `if(optionI){
            convertToLow(buffer);
        }
        if(optionS){
            deblank(buffer);
        }
        if(optionO){`   Where are those items set and what are they expected to do?

Comment: where is the `FILE *` set?  please post all the relevant  code

Comment: if `optionO` is not 'true1 then the calls to `fprintf( output,`.. ) will never be executed  So, how is that value set?

Comment: i don't feel comfortable posting my whole code online because it is homework , i can send you private

Comment: regarding: `free(buffer); `  if going to do this within the loop, then the next line needs to be `buffer = NULL;`  otherwise the next call to `getline()` will try to use the value in `buffer`, expecting it to be a valid pointer to allocated memory

Comment: Because it is homework, it is YOUR code, so you can do with it as you wish, including posting it on stackoverflow.com

Comment: the results of the call to your function: `is_ok()` can result in the line not being output to the output file.  So really need to post that function

Comment: in general, when debugging code, start with the simplest thing then add features one at a time

Comment: thank you for your help..
`is_ok()` checks for palindrome

Comment: `static int is_ok(char *source){

    int i;
    int len = strlen(source);
    int ok = 1;
 
    for(i = 0; i < (len/2) ; i++){
        if(source[i] != source[len - 1 - i]){
            return 0;

        }
    }

    return 1;
    
}`

Comment: do not place code in comments, rather, edit the question

Comment: the `is_ok()` seems to be checking that the second half of the line is a reflection of the first half of the line.  a condition that is very unlikely to be true. No wonder your not getting any printed output.

Comment: No, that's not a problem but thanks anyway for helping.